# Split string using Dojo/Dijit

Tags: java, javascript, dojo, multi-select, dijit.form

Here is my problem,

I have a dojo/dijit multiselect list, so after a multiple select i need to split the result

Example

```
 var selecteted = dijit.byId('list1').attr('value');
```

let assume that selected = 'value 1,value2,value3';

so afer i have multiple result i do as follow in order to split it

```
var splited = new Array();
splited = selected.split(',');
```

but this code failed, for some reason the 'selected' variable is some dojo/dijit object which is not compatible with java script 'split' ...

so i m wondering , is dojo has their own split implementation ?
also i would be glad to share me your opinios..

Thanks

EDIT

After a litle debug with Firebug i found out that 'selected' format is array, so actualy split is not necessary anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dijit.form.Multiselect already gives an array (of selected stuff) when you get its value property. There is no need to do a split.

Comment: Yes, that is what i just found out during debug :) Thanks for the comment.